# why unity3d builds are so large?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

Since I started with unity3D, I noticed something with my builds, they are heavy. I created a simple 2D game project with nothing and build a blank game for mac 86_64 and i get 44mb game, I have similar size with building windows, but in Android build I have 19MB and HTML5 4MB something is very wrong here.

When I go to the publisher log they say (this is Mac86_64 version build):

```
Textures      0.0 kb     0.0% 
Meshes        0.0 kb     0.0% 
Animations    0.0 kb     0.0% 
Sounds        0.0 kb     0.0% 
Shaders       0.0 kb     0.0% 
Other Assets  0.5 kb     0.0% 
Levels        4.7 kb     0.1% 
Scripts       526.1 kb   11.5% 
Included DLLs 3.9 mb     88.2% 
File headers  8.9 kb     0.2% 
Complete size 4.5 mb     100.0%
```

But the file actually is 44,3 MB
This is normal? what can i make to reduce that size? 19MB for a empty Android game is too heavy.

Thanks a Lot,

Comment: According to my knowledge, the size won't increase that much. Of course that depends on the game you are developing.

Comment: The thing is that to get the engine working it should include some essential files. Anyway I don't think 19mb for a base engine is too much today where a low-end smartphone have at least 16Gb of storage.